# Add layer underneath subviews

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, avplayer, avplayerlayer

I am trying to add a sublayer of the function `setupPlayerView` below subviews which have been loaded previously. The subviews are loaded faster than the layer as the function creating the layer uses a string which is modified from another class, a `UIViewController` (I want to load individual videos). I found an answer on stackoverflow but the suggested solution of `.insertSublayer(playerLayer, below: self.controlsContainerView.layer)` did not work for me. How can I ensure the videolayer is under all my other subviews like `controlsContainerView` and its subviews (e.g. `activityIndicatorView`) in turn?

Here is what I got right now:

```
class PlayerView: UIView {

var urlString: String? {
    didSet {
        setupPlayerView()
    }
}

override init(frame: CGRect){

    super.init(frame: frame)

    //although the function is called immediately it is not the "lower" than everything else
    setupPlayerView()

    //add subview with controls (e.g. spinner)
    controlsContainerView.frame = frame
    addSubview(controlsContainerView)

    //add to subview and center spinner in subview
    controlsContainerView.addSubview(activityIndicatorView) // (spinner)
    controlsContainerView.addSubview(whiteView)

    //...
}

//... irrelevant code (closures like `activityIndicatorView` and `whiteView`)

//setup video player
func setupPlayerView() {

    if let urlString = self.urlString, let videoURL = NSURL(string: urlString){

        print(urlString)

        //player's video
        if self.player == nil {
            player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL as URL)
        }

        //add sub-layer
        let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
        playerLayer.frame = self.frame
        self.controlsContainerView.layer.insertSublayer(playerLayer, below: self.controlsContainerView.layer)

        //when are frames actually rendered (when is video loaded so one can remove spinner)
        player?.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "currentItem.loadedTimeRanges", options: .new, context: nil)

    }

}
```

For those interested: I change `urlString` the following way in another class (a ViewController):

```
videoPlayerView.urlString = videoUrl //videoUrl being some link to a video source
```

Comment: Try inserting it a index 0, rather than relative to another view.

Comment: inserting sub layer or adding subview causes addition over top of view stack.

Try inserting at index 0 or the index of the layer you trying to place new one underneath.

Comment: Works! Thank you!